# Call ktor http client asynchronously in a suspend function

Tags: kotlin, ktor, ktor-client

I have the following function that uses ktor's HttpClient. and the tokenService getAccessToken function also uses ktor client and fetches a token.

```
suspend fun addUser(user: User): User {
    return client.post("${Base}api/v1/adduser") {
        contentType(ContentType.Application.Json)
        header("Authorization", "Bearer ${tokenService.getAccessToken()}")
        body = user
    }
}
```

and this is my simple test

```
@Test
fun `should add user`() = runBlocking {
    delay(3000)
    val user = userService.addUser(User("john doe"))
    user.firstName shouldBe "john doe"
}
```

now the test passes because of the delay, the delay gives time for the token to be fetched first, but if I remove the delay the addUser function gets called without fetching the token first. My question is, is there a better way to do this, to avoid adding delay to tests.
I looked at Kotlin Flows but I don't know how to implement it for my scenario.
If you could point me in the right direction I would be grateful.

Comment: That's strange because if I use your code and put a delay (for testing purpose) to the `tokenService.getAccessToken()` method then `addUser` always waits for its completion. What `tokenService.getAccessToken()` returns without delay in your test?

Comment: since the tokenServcie.getAccessToken() is a network call, it needs a few seconds. when you try it if you just return some text for a test that would be fast enough so there won't be any problems. when I run my code the addUser gets called without the token header and throws error.

Comment: That's why I tried to put a big enough delay to emulate a network call. Here is the similar code that works as expected https://gist.github.com/Stexxe/ce539589129e5e529d1c30564b0c7951.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue with unit testing in general. Think of the scenario of when you have to make a request to a database, we don't want to spin up and entire database just to unit test that, it would make testing slow and cumbersome. We want fast feedback from our unit tests rather than adding delays everywhere.

A common approach is to use a mocking library like `Mockito` or `Mockk` to mock the network service (in your case `tokenService`). If you used `Mockito` [reference](https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin/mockito#using-mockito-with-kotlin) you could  do something like this:

```
val mockTokenService = Mockito.mock(TokenService::class.java)
Mockito.`when`(mockTokenService.getAccessToken()).thenReturn("sampleToken123")
```

That way you could remove `delay(3000)` from your unit test. Then you'll know your `addUser` method business logic will be correct if the test passes, and you can test the token service separately, perhaps with a more-involved integration test or with other mocks if you so choose.